# Kdenlive not showing preview in "clip monitor" on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, flatpak, kdenlive

I just installed Kdenlive's Flatpak (version 22.04.3) following the instructions from the official website. It is not the first time I use Kdenlive.

However, when I import the project, the clip monitor won't show the preview. Tried to reinstall but no luck.

[image: Kdenlive clip monitor won't show preview]

This is my system's info:

- Dell Inspiron 3442, 8GB RAM (0651)
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210U CPU @ 1.70GHz
- Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller
- Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller

`lsmod` command output:

```
drm_kms_helper        307200  1 i915
cec                    61440  2 drm_kms_helper,i915
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            20480  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   606208  15 drm_kms_helper,i915,ttm
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, nevermind. Uninstalled the flatpak and reinstall with PPA.
Problem solved.

Comment: Glad that you solved your issue! Can you please [edit] your answer and add a bit more details, like the exact PPA you used and how to reinstall Kdenlive using it? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Menu View and make sure you have both Clip Monitor and Project Monitor checked.